# Angular Flex layout is throwing error when I add layout module

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am getting the following error when I add FlexLayoutModule to the imports section of my app.module.ts

> ERROR in The target entry-point "@angular/flex-layout" has missing
>   dependencies:
>    - @angular/core
>    - @angular/common
>    - rxjs
>    - @angular/platform-browser

I never recall getting this in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I reinstalled angular flex and all now seems okay. Very odd. but easily fixed thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when I forgot to install 'Angular-Flex' and tried using it. Did an install and worked.